# Macro for Text to columns

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

'
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination := Range("A3"), DataType := xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo := Array(Array(0,1),Array(60,1),Array(63,1),Array(68,1),Array(71,1), _
        Array(85,1),Array(88,1),Array(93,1),Array(99,1),Array(107,1),Array(111,1),Array _
        (120,1),Array(123,1),Array(127,1),Array(130,1),Array(134,1),Array(143,1),Array( _
        147,1),Array(157,1),Array(162,1),Array(165,1),Array(170,1),Array(202,1),Array( _
        233,1),Array(236,1),Array(238,1),Array(248,1),Array(251,1),Array(260,1),Array( _
        265,1),Array(277,1),Array(283,1),Array(287,1),Array(291,1),Array(295,1),Array( _
        299,1),Array(302,1),Array(306,1),Array(310,1),Array(322,1),Array(326,1),Array( _
        332,1),Array(335,1),Array(338,1),Array(344,1),Array(348,1),Array(356,1),Array( _
        360,1),Array(367,1),Array(373,1),Array(375,1),Array(384,1),Array(387,1),Array( _
        394,1),Array(398,1),Array(403,1),Array(409,1),Array(413,1),Array(419,1),Array( _
        424,1),Array(429,1),Array(432,1),Array(438,1),Array(444,1),Array(449,1),Array( _
        454,1),Array(458,1),Array(463,1),Array(468,1),Array(474,1),Array(478,1),Array( _
        481,1),Array(484,1),Array(489,1),Array(493,1),Array(524,1),Array(554,1),Array( _
        557,1),Array(563,1),Array(565,1),Array(577,1),Array(594,1),Array(613,1),Array( _
        616,1),Array(620,1),Array(626,1),Array(629,1),Array(634,1),Array(646,1),Array( _
        654,1),Array(659,1),Array(667,1),Array(669,1),Array(675,1),Array(683,1),Array( _
        689,1),Array(696,1),Array(699,1),Array(706,1),Array(714,1),Array(717,1),Array( _
        721,1),Array(728,1),Array(730,1),Array(743,1),Array(751,1),Array(754,1),Array( _
        758,1),Array(767,1),Array(774,1),Array(779,1),Array(787,1),Array(790,1),Array( _
        798,1),Array(805,1),Array(808,1),Array(817,1),Array(822,1),Array(826,1),Array( _
        835,1),Array(845,1),Array(853,1),Array(857,1),Array(864,1),Array(869,1),Array( _
        877,1),Array(881,1),Array(891,1),Array(895,1),Array(903,1),Array(912,1),Array( _
        916,1),Array(920,1),Array(927,1),Array(933,1),Array(937,1),Array(941,1),Array( _

End Sub
```

I have 800 words in cell A3 in sheet input1, i recorded above macro by using function "Text to columns" in Excel 2007 which is giving error "Too many line continuations".

Can someone tell me the exact code please, indeed I want to add all the 800 words in different individual cells as one word in each cell in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to tell the Macro Recorder to create longer lines so I do not think `TextToColumns` can be made to record this code for you.

You are using the fixed width option so words are starting at position 0, 60, 63, 68, 71 and so on.  The start positions for about 120 words have been have been recorded so, if you wanted to build an array like this, you will have a lot of typing.

You say "words".  To me that implies variable length strings separated by spaces.  If that is correct, try the code below.  It uses function `Split` to split cell A3 into words by space.  These are then spread out along row 4 with any gaps created by double or triple spaces ignored.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitCell()

  Dim CellCrnt As Long
  Dim InxW As Long
  Dim Word() As String

  With Worksheets("input1")

    Word = Split(.Range("A3"), " ")

    CellCrnt = 1

    For InxW = LBound(Word) To UBound(Word)
      ' Any double spaces will cause empty entries in Word.
      ' Ignore these empty entries
      If Word(InxW) <> "" Then
        .Cells(4, CellCrnt).Value = Word(InxW)
        CellCrnt = CellCrnt + 1
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please also help me out by answering my question already put today with title-Import data from word file to excel by using macro

Comment: @Sidharth  Sorry I do not know Word VBA.  If I want to transfer data from Word to Excel, I: (1) Select All within Word, (2) Paste to an Excel Worksheet and (3) use Excel VBA to tidy up the result as necessary.